# Second layer of overlays on map view

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay

I have an Android MapView in which i need to have a second layer of overlayed pins, over the one that the MapView already handles.

To accomplish this I have placed a FrameLayout over my MapView, and placed my pins as ImageViews in that Layout.

I have overridden the Draw() method of the ImageViews to update their position when the map moves (so that the pins move with it) like this:

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    if(mCoordinates != null && mapView != null){
        LayoutParams mParams = (LayoutParams)this.getLayoutParams();
        mapView.getProjection().toPixels(mCoordinates, newPosition);
        mParams.leftMargin = newPosition.x;
        mParams.topMargin = newPosition.y;
    }
    super.draw(canvas);
}
```

The problem: views are updating too slowly, so when I move the map the pins seem to lagg behind it.

Any insights on approach or implementation welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end we just mad a method that would order the overlays every time so that the big overlays were always painted first and the small ones over those.

Answer (score 0):

I have an app that uses multiple overlays to do the job. Each overlay is processed as needed. At the end of processing, the function(s) call the map update routine. Here's a skeleton of the update routine.

```
    private void updateMap() {
    GeoPoint geoPoint;
    overlayList = mapView.getOverlays();
    overlayList.clear();
    locationOverlay = new MapOverlay();
    pushpinOverlay = new MapOverlay();
    arrowOverlay = new ArrowOverlay();
    tapOverlay = new TapOverlay();
    if (hasCurrentPosition) {
        locationOverlay.setDrawId(R.drawable.man);
        geoPoint = new GeoPoint(currentLatitudeE6, currentLongitudeE6);
        locationOverlay.setPointToDraw(geoPoint);
        if (isFirstFix) {
            mapController.animateTo(geoPoint);
            isFirstFix = false;
        }
    }
    if (hasPushpinPosition) {
        pushpinOverlay.setDrawId(R.drawable.locationmarker);
        geoPoint = new GeoPoint(pushpinLatitudeE6, pushpinLongitudeE6);
        pushpinOverlay.setPointToDraw(geoPoint);
    }
    calcDistance();
    if (findFlag) {
        calcArrowRotation();
    }
    setStatusMessage();
    overlayList.add(locationOverlay);
    overlayList.add(pushpinOverlay);
    if (findFlag) {
        overlayList.add(arrowOverlay);
    }
    overlayList.add(tapOverlay);
    mapView.invalidate();
}
```

The tap overlay is the "top" overlay and has to be added last. The jpushpin and location images are 'locked' to the map because they are specified as lat and long. The tap overlay returns the map point that was tapped and not the screen point. The arrow is positons on the screen and only rotates and does not move horizontally or vertically. Also, the arrow overlay is toggled on and off by the user (findFlag is a boolean value toggled by a button).

Maybe you can use a variation of this theme with an itemized overlay as one of the layered overlays?

Comment: Thank you for your answer but as i said i cannot use the MapView.getOverlays(), due to specific requirements in the application